# Make vim recognise COOL syntax

Tags: vim, vi

I am using vim 8.1 on macOS (vim-plug for plugin management). I need to work with COOL files, so I manually downloaded the [syntax file](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1216) and put it in `~/.vim/syntax`

I added the following line to my `.vimrc` in order to associate the `.cl` extension with COOL:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cl setf cool
```

However, when I load `.cl` files into vim, it fails to recognise the language.

```
:verbose set ft ?
```

yields:

```
filetype=lisp
Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.0650/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim line 875
```

Changing the `.virmc` line to:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cool setf cool
```

makes vim recognise the files as COOL.

What should I do in order to have `.cl` default to COOL instead of LISP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the file `~/.vim/filetype.vim` with the following content:

```
augroup filetypedetect
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cl setf cool
augroup END
```

See `:help new-filetype`.